# error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'List<double>::node'

Tags: c++, templates

So, for a project, I'm implementing a type of list as a template class using a linked list with a head and tail pointer. When I construct the list I use the following code

```
template <class Item>
List<Item>::List()
{
        if (typeid(Item) == typeid(string))
        {
                head = new node("0", NULL, NULL);
                tail = new node("0", NULL, NULL);
        }
        else
        {
                head = new node(0, NULL, NULL);
                tail = new node(0, NULL, NULL);
        }
        head->next = tail;
        tail->prev = head;
        cursor = head;

        size = 0;
}
```

The typeid if statement is there so that if I'm making a list of strings the node constructor will receive a proper string value and the compiler won't throw a fit. That works fine, however when I edited my code so that it would also initialize a list of doubles the compiler threw this error:

/List.h:59:21: error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'List::node'
                head = new node("0", NULL, NULL);

As far as I can tell the compiler is ignoring the if statement I've placed but I don't know why. If I remove the code to allow strings and just use the statements in the else block then doubles, ints, chars, etc work fine but then strings won't work. I've verified that the if statement is returning the correct value for what type Item is as well so I'm stumped as to why the compiler doesn't like this.

I'm pretty sure there are better ways of doing this out there, but is anyone able to offer a solution to fix this particular piece of code? Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: You can call the constructor of the Item, as Item(), to initialize the node object. head = new node(Item(),NULL,NULL)

Comment: why do you need the string to be initialised to `"0"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the constructor of the template parameter to initialize the objects while working on teplates. You don't need typeid.
You could just write

```
head = new node(Item(), NULL, NULL);
tail = new node(Item(), NULL, NULL);
```

Only thing that you have to take care of is that, the type you are using must have a default constructor and it has to be copyable

With this your strings will be inisialized to an empty string